# Best practice of multiple steps flow

Tags: node.js, queue, rabbitmq

I have a service that gets POST to '/'. This service pushes the message to a RABBITMQ queue, which process the message. I want to get back indication when finished, then call to another function which do another processing.
The scenario:

(http)->server1->RABBITMQ QUEUE-> RABBITMQ CONSUMER->back to server1-> call function A

The server is NODE JS

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Promise chain could be useful in your case. It will execute all async steps one by one, and if any of them fails, error will be catched.

```
const doSomethingStepByStep = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
  // call server, or whatever - here just an example that promise is resolved
  return Promise.resolve()
  })
.then(() => {
  // etc, call another server
  })
.catch(ex => {
    // something went wrong in either in the steps above
  })
}

// use it
doSomethingStepByStep()
  .then((res) => {
// do something with the result
})
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the "Process Manager" pattern for messaging http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html

as well as the "saga" (https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/ and https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/05/14/saga-patterns-wrap-up/) or "workflow manager" patterns, which are basically the same thing but with different names.

the gist of it is that you have a central piece of code that understands the over-all flow of the process. it handles sending out the right message at the right time, receiving a response, processing that response to figure out what happens next, and making the next call so that the next step in the process can happen.

I have a blog post that covers this core idea, moving from simple JS objects in Node, out to RabbitMQ with these concepts https://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/